# How to modify / add CUPS printer attributes like marker-colors, marker-levels or marker-names?

Tags: cups, printer

If I add a printer through the GUI the /etc/cups/printers.conf contains:

```
<Printer printername>
...
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
Attribute marker-colors \#000000,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,none,#000000,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,none,none
Attribute marker-levels 100,99,99,100,0,100,100,100,100,100,100
Attribute marker-types toner,toner,toner,toner,waste-toner,opc,opc,opc,opc,fuser,other
Attribute marker-change-time 1683632924
</Printer>
```

If I add the printer through the terminal with:

```
lpadmin -p <printername> -E -v socket://<ip> -P /etc/cups/ppd_template/<custom_ppd>.ppd -L "<location>" -D "<desc>"
```

it misses all lines starting with "Attribute":

```
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
</Printer>
```

As they are probably important and I'm not able to use the GUI, I need a command-line solution.

I already tried several ways, but although the commands succeed, they do not add anything to the printers.conf:

```
lpadmin -p <printername> -E -o marker-levels=100,99,99,100,0,100,100,100,100,100,100
lpadmin -p <printername> -E -o MarkerLevels=100,99,99,100,0,100,100,100,100,100,100
lpadmin -p <printername> -E -o AttributeMarkerLevels=100,99,99,100,0,100,100,100,100,100,100
lpadmin -p <printername> -E -o "Attribute=marker-levels 100,99,99,100,0,100,100,100,100,100,100"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out by myself: Those values aren't set through installation. Instead they appear after a print job has been done. I suppose cups creates ipp requests while printing and the printer responds with the current `marker-level` of the toners, which is then written to printers.conf.